# MSSQL 2008: Get unique values from a many-to-many table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following temp table (#associations):

```
create table #associations (ID1 nvarchar(max), ID2 nvarchar(max))
insert into #associations (ID1,ID2) values
    (1,2)
    ,(1,3)
    ,(2,1)
    ,(2,3)
    ,(3,1)
    ,(3,2)

ID1   ID2
1    2
1    3
2    1
2    3
3    1
3    2
```

All IDs are related to each other, and so the relationships in ID1 and ID2 occasionally repeat in the opposite direction.

What I need to be able to do, is select back a completely unique result set for any number of relationships (more than 3 in the example above) in a comma-delimited list, like the following:

```
ID   Relationship
1    2,3
2    3
```

So far, I have the following SQL, however, it doesn't flatten into unique relationships (i.e. I get both directions covered in the results):

```
select distinct
    a.id1 as [ID] 
    ,stuff(
    (
        select ', ' + a2.id1 
        from #associations a2
        where a2.id2 = a.id1    
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') as [Relationship]
    from #associations a
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional check in your co-related query like this `AND a.id1  > a2.id1`

```
select distinct
    a.id1 as [ID] 
    ,stuff(
    (
        select ', ' + a2.id1 
        from #associations a2
        where a2.id2 = a.id1  
        AND a.id1  > a2.id1  
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') as [Relationship]
    from #associations a
```

This will restrict repetitive relation.

You may additionally have to do a `UNION` of `#associations` before the relation query like this.

```
SELECT ID1, ID2 FROM #associations
UNION 
SELECT ID2 AS ID1, ID1 as ID2 FROM #associations
```

and use this in your query instead of `#associations`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;with a as (
select distinct case when a.ID1 < a.ID2 then a.ID1 else a.ID2 end ID1
    , case when a.ID1 < a.ID2 then a.ID2 else a.ID1 end ID2
from #associations a
)
select distinct a.ID1 as [ID]
    , STUFF((select ', '+a2.ID2 from a a2 where a.ID1 = a2.ID1 for xml path('')),1,2,'') as [Relationship]
from a
```

If the ID1 is less than ID2, then use ID1 as first id and ID2 as second id, otherwise swap ID1 and ID2.